# Rancher v1.3.1 Kubernetes Dashboard not working

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I try to install Rancher v1.3.1 and enable Kubernetes Environment, the install seem OK but when i navigate to Dashboard but result is blank page, i check 2 deployment :kubernetes-dashboard and tiller-deploy restart every time with log:

Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service accounts configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a server that does not exist. Reason: Get https://10.43.0.1:443/version: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: i/o timeout

I dont know why, Please help me

I dont know why kubernetes service for expose 10.43.0.1:443 belong different namespace(default) with others(kube-system)

Comment: try to ask these questions directly to ranchers slack.

Answer (score 0):

Please try switching from using https://10.43.0.1:443 to http://10.43.0.1 by editing the following in the deployment.

```
          args:
            - --auto-generate-certificates
            - --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
            # Uncomment the following line to manually specify Kubernetes API server Host
            # If not specified, Dashboard will attempt to auto discover the API server and connect
            # to it. Uncomment only if the default does not work.
            - --apiserver-host=http://10.43.0.1
```